# Comparing data in the same table for non existent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, not-exists

I have a table that has both Company name and Contacts for their respective companies. Type column has a 0 or 1 indicating whether it is a company or person.  Each row has a column with a unique contact no.  The 'person' row has a column called "Company no." that links the person to the company.  I'm trying to return rows that show a company without any contacts in the same table.  Not sure how to even start writing this query.

Comment: You really should change your table's design! Never mix to different data in one table!

Comment: It's out of the box Microsoft table...not my design...

Comment: If you have to stick to this table it can be done of course... Please provide your table's structure and sample data and expected output. What have your tried so far?

Comment: Contact No_    Name    Type    Company No_

Comment: Hi Craig, really! This is not "your table's structure" and it is very far away from "sample data" and "expected output... Please use the edit option to add more details to your question...

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do.  It puts it all in one sentence instead of showing you what my column headers look like.  I've tried indenting each line...am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi Craig, You should use the edit option of the quesiton, not the comment :-)  If you look at my answer you see, how one can easily create testable data in a non-persistent table. If you add such data do your question the next time you'll get much more and better answers. It was bit annoying for me to type this in...

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ContactNo INT, Name VARCHAR(100), [Type] INT,CompanyNo INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (100,'ACME, Inc.',0,100)
,(200,'Bob Smith',1,100)
,(300,'John Doe',1,100)
,(400,'Widget World',0,400)
,(500,'Fishing, Inc.',0,500)
,(600,'Jane Doe',1,500);

WITH TheCompanies AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    WHERE tbl.[Type]=0
)
SELECT *
FROM TheCompanies
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tbl WHERE [Type]=1 AND CompanyNo=TheCompanies.CompanyNo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Was not my intention to annoy, only to learn.  Those that can, do.  Those that can't, teach.  You've taught me today.